# Wiggling path transitions with D3

Tags: d3.js

I use a line generator for my paths and try to transition them, but even if I don't use interpolation, I end up with wiggling paths.

```
const createLineData = d3.svg.line()
  .x(d => d.x)
  .y(d => d.y)

...

path.enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('stroke', '#f00')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1)
  .attr('fill', 'none')

path
  .transition()
  .duration(200)
  .attr('d', createLineData)

path.exit().remove()
```

**How do I prevent the wiggling?**

[image]

Comment: This could be of interest: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/

Comment: This seems to be the problem, but I don't have a timeline. I show these paths on a map. The last point of the path is deleted at the tail and the new point is added at the head. So it's moving in x/y and not just in x

Comment: Could you provide a complete example please? It's not clear to me what you mean by "wiggling".

Comment: I added an example gif.